# Sphinx Search - Optional filters

Tags: php, sphinx

I'm pretty new to sphinx search and i'm having some issues with my query.

I have the following config:

```
sql_attr_uint = user
sql_attr_uint = category
sql_field_string = title
sql_field_string = description
```

The query looks like

```
$sf->setMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_ANY);
$sf->setFilter("user", array("1033"));
$sf->setFilter("category", array("9"));
$sf->setFieldWeights(array("user"=>150,"category"=>50,"title"=>75,"description"=>75));

$result = $sf->query('my test query',"test");
```

I would like to query all rows that match any of the filters, and sort them by the number of filters they match, on the priority user > title = description > category

Basicaly, i'd need the filters to weight, rather than removing the unmatching rows.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Basicaly, i'd need the filters to weight, rather than removing the unmatching rows.

While basically possible, its frought with difficulties.

better is just to convert uint attributes to full-text keywords,

change sql_attr_uint to sql_field_string so become fields (assuming you want to keep them as attributes too, if not just remove the line and let them default to fields)

Then can filter using extended syntax

```
$cl->setMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED);
$cl->Query('"my test query"/1 | (@user 1099) | (@category 9)',"test");
```

(this is also using quorum syntax to emulate a ANY query)